# Come to (regain consciousness) and pull to (shut)

Tags: phrasal-verbs, reflexives

I don't know if it's part of my regional dialect, but around these parts we use the phrase "[pull to](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+to)" to mean 'close the door all the way.' It wasn't until last week that it struck me as odd. Pull the door to...what? To itself?

I didn't find much explanation on *pull to* as a phrasal verb, but a friend pointed out that it was probably like "[come to](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+to)", which he always figured was reflexive and essentially a shortening of "come to one's senses".

So in terms of these two phrasal verbs, *pull to* and *come to*, are they reflexive? And if so, why does the object get dropped? Is that a usual occurrence or do these two examples represent some kind of unusual feature of English?

Comment: Are you in Pennsylvania, by any chance? My first thought is German influence via Pennsylvania Dutch (or similar). The *to* not being a preposition, but a separable prefix.

Comment: OED's first citation is from 1673, a stage direction "She pulls the door to."

Comment: @RegDwigнt I can't hazard its origins but my guess is this is a common expression, because my first thought was 'Are you in Yorkshire, by any chance?'  "Pull the door to" (as an instruction to another) would be a good example of why it's perfectly Ok to end a sentence with a preposition.

Comment: FWIW, I have not heard this phrase in either the Midwest US or East Texas.

Comment: In Norfolk (eastern county in England), they say 'he pulled the door to'. meaning that he didn't exactly shut the door but just closed it. I suppose it is part of standard Queen's English too, but in spite of having lived away from Norfolk for over 40 years it is one of those things I'm not certain about. Is it just a Norfolk idiom? Can anyone help me? Interestingly when they use it they pronounce the 'to' slightly differently to usual, they say 'tew'. Whereas they would say 'I went t'Norwich', although the 'to' is exactly the same word.

Comment: I had always assumed it's standard English to "pull the door to" - and I agree that it means *not fully shut/closed*.

Comment: @WS2 and Trevor, I hadn't thought of that distinction but you're right - it means pulling the door almost closed but without it shutting completely.

Comment: @TrevorD. Great minds think alike, again. I've since found it in the OED, see below.

Comment: Following the above comments, "push the door to" can also be used with the same meaning from the other side of the door.

Comment: @Trevor D. But in standard Queen's English is the 'to' pronounced exactly as it is when used in other ways, such as 'I went to the shop'. I don't think it is. But my vowel sounds are so corrupted by my early life in Norfolk that frankly I am all over the place with them.

Comment: @WS2 I'm not aware of any difference in pronunciation. In my 'standard southern' accent, I pronounce the *to* just as I would in any other context.

Comment: @TrevorD. Really? Just like 'going to the shop'? That becomes in effect 'tu the shop'. But when you pull the door closed, doesn't it sound like 'pull it too'?

Comment: @WS2 The "to" may be slightly more stretched, but I would put that down to it being at the end of the 'sentence'. (But I'm not good on pronunciation!)

Comment: @TrevorD Yes, that's it. It's because it's at the end of the sentence. How silly of me not to realise that.

Comment: Presumably we can all agree that DH Lawrence is a competent writer with full command of the language. If he thinks [The curtains were pulled to.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22finished+the+curtains+were+pulled+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is a valid English sentence, that's good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it means pull to "close".  I also found this:
"[Anticausative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticausative_verb)" reflexive denotes that the (usually inanimate) subject of the verb undergoes an action or change of state whose agent is unclear or nonexistent.  The example that was given was "English - The door (was, got) opened." I believe this could apply to "pull to" or the phrase "pull to close" the door.

Answer (score 0):

"Pull the door to" is a common expression in the Southeastern U.S. It isn't as common as it used to be but my generation still uses it and I'm in my 50's.